# What is chat in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, modern-life, technology

What would be a good Latin noun or verb to translate "chat" in the sense that would apply to [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm), for example?
There are verbs like *garrire*, *fabulari*, *verbigerare*, and simply *colloqui* but I don't know which one would have the most suitable tone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion *garrire* is perfectly all right for inconsequential chatter. *Colloqui* is pretty generally applicable, but there's really no shortage of options to use for 'chat'. A few are:

*res cum aliquo agitare; de rebus cum aliquo colloqui; 
sermonem cum aliquo conferre.*

I particularly like [*inter sese*] *vicos et urbem laudare*, which I remember from my schooldays and which think is from Horace, Ser. I, 9.